# Change package image in the enterprise architect tree view

Tags: enterprise-architect

I want to change the image of a enterprise architect package in the tree view in a project from an addin.

Is there a way to change the image of a specific package (e.g. change the color of the package symbol to blue)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot change the image of packages.

You **can** do that for Elements using a UML profile, setting the icon and _metaType attributes on the stereotype class.

The icon used should be a 16x16 bitmap. Use the color C0C0C0 (192,192,192) as the color to indicate transparency

**Edit**

It appears that the mechanism described above also works for packages. See Thomas Kilians answer.

Comment: I also found that topic in the EA documentation. It seems that this is the best option. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Though Geert is right in most cases - here he isn't. Actually you can use the same mechanism also for packages. Just assign `Icon` and `_metatype` and you see a different icon even for packages:

[image]

I just did that with some arbitrary test data.

Comment: Ah, that must have changed recently then. I'm sure we had this question on the forum a couple of years ago, and one of the Sparxians told us it was not possible. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @GeertBellekens I know what you're talking about ;-) Btw. "See", not "Zie" :o)